# Como converter Scanner para double em java?

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um software, no qual em um momento o sistema deve pegar um valor informado pelo usuário usando a classe Scanner e inseri-lo em um array e depois devolver um array com os valores digitados pelo usuário, mas eu não consigo fazer a conversão de Scanner para double. Segue a linha de código:

```
  double[] a = [Double.parseDouble(vlrus.nextDouble() + "")];
```

Comment: De Scanner pra Double?
não seria de  Double para Int?

Comment: Pode ser, por que o exercício não deixou claro que seria um tipo específico.

Comment: fiquei confuso, pois Scanner é uma função, e não um tipo primitivo

Answer (score 1):

Não vejo motivo para você tentar usar um array aqui. Acho que o que você quer é apenas isso:

```
double a = vlrus.nextDouble();
```

Para então guardar o resultado no array:

```
double[] b = new double[] {a};
```

Comment: Na questão é pedido para ler dados do teclado e armazená-los em um array

Comment: @MarcosPauloS.Rezende Então, edite a pergunta deixando claro o que você precisa. Sua pergunta nada falava de arrays. Editei a resposta para mostrar como criar um array com o valor lido.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado.